# Locking/Unlocking Mutexes out of Scope to process Switch statement

Tags: c++

```
EventType event; 

_mutex.lock();
while (!_event_queue.empty()) {
    event = _event_queue.front();
    _event_queue.pop();
    _mutex.unlock();

    /** Handle Event */
    switch (event) {
```

Is this valid? I'm trying to figure out how handle an event in the queue as and when we receive one. `_mutex` is a private variable to the class. And it is being used to safely push updates in the queue from another thread, using:

```
_mutex.lock();
_event_queue.push(LONG_EVENT);
_mutex.unlock();
```

Comment: You should be managing your locks with a [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) to be sure no lock leaks.

Comment: You will have to be sure to relock the mutex before each iteration ends. Unlocking an unlocked mutex is undefined behavior.

Comment: Perhaps [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) suits your needs?